# Ich dachte vs Ich dachte mir

Tags: word-usage

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen

> Ich dachte

und

> Ich dachte mir?

Ich bin der Ansicht, dass "Ich dachte mir" eher einen längeren Denkprozess beschreibt als ohne "mir".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ich dachte* bezieht sich eher auf Wissen oder Fakten, *ich dachte mir* eher eine Überlegung.

Comment: Wobei sich für Überlegungen beides verwenden lässt:
Ich dachte Trump ist ein schlechter Präsident. Ich dachte mir Trump ist ein schlechter Präsident.

Comment: darum schrieb ich "eher"

Comment: Na, da hast du aber etwas arg verkürzt. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, ‘Ich dachte, dass *p*’ implies (or at least leaves open) that *p* is false. By contrast, ‘Ich dachte mir (schon), dass *p*’ implies that *p* is true. In technical terms, the latter is factive while the former is not.

To illustrate, suppose you’ve been told that Peter is on holiday. But now someone else tells you they just had lunch with Peter. Surprised, you might say:

„Ich dachte, dass Peter im Urlaub ist!“ / „Ich dachte, Peter sei im Urlaub.“

So, it’s almost like saying: ‘But isn’t he on holiday?’

Now assume you go to Peter’s house, but he isn’t there. His neighbour tells you he’s gone to France for two weeks. You might say:

„Ich dachte mir (schon), dass Peter im Urlaub ist!“ / „Ich dachte mir, Peter könnte im Urlaub sein.“

So, it’s a bit like ‘I thought he might be on holiday.’

Note that you couldn’t felicitously say „Ich dachte mir (schon), dass Peter im Urlaub ist!“ in the first scenario. Nor could you say „Ich dachte, dass Peter im Urlaub ist!“ in the second.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, kleiner Hinweis: bei Deutschen Fragen werden Deutsche Antworten bevorzugt.

Answer (score 1):

Keine Ahnung, ob die Übersetzung zu 100% passt, aber meiner Meinung nach:

- "etw. denken" (*Ich dachte, ich bringe dir etwas zu essen mit*) <=> "to think sth." (*I thought I'd bring you something to eat*)
- "sich etw. denken" (*Ich dachte mir, ich bringe dir etwas zu essen mit*) <=> "to figure sth." (*I figured I'd bring you something to eat*)

Zweiter Fall ist eine Teilmenge des ersten und betont, dass es sich um einen selbst entwickelten Gedanken handelt (nicht bloß eine Beobachtung der Fakten). Anders gesagt: "Ich komme zum Schluss, dass.. " oder "Ich habe die Idee, dass.. ".